# Checking whether username exists or not code in sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written a code to check whether the username exists in the database or not. It seems to return that there is no such username exists even if there's a same username existing.

```
$conu=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_pass","db_name");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM member WHERE username = $username");
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$user_err = "<i><span class='error'>Usernme already exists</span></i>";
    $errflag = true;
}
elseif(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}$/", $username) === 0) {
    $user_err = "<i><span class='error'>Usernme must be bigger than 5 chararacters and can contain only digits, letters and underscore</span></i>";
    $errflag = true;
}
```

Comment: You are likely **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mysql_query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1;");
```

`SELECT 1` is not actually using the database; it's always returning `1`, hence why your result is always the same regardless of the contents of the `member` table.

Answer (score 0):

Usernames I take it are some sort of varchar?  If that is the case, you might want to put its value in quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `member` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' LIMIT 1;");
```

your query is subject to sql injections btw.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you are trying to return a column that probably doesn't exist: "1"
Second, I hope that you are cleaning the $username or else you are allowing anyone to inject your database.

The correct query is

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username`='$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using mysqli to connect, but mysql to perform your query.
2. When you `SELECT 1 FROM member WHERE username = $username`, the result will always be `1`.
3. You need to put `$username` in the query in quotes. Something like `SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = '$username'`.
4. You forgot to include the part of the code for when there is no such username in your posting.